# How to add space between the characters if two consecutive characters are equal in c?

Tags: c

I need to add add space if two consecutive characters are same.

For example:
input:

```
ttjjjiibbbbhhhhhppuuuu
```

Output:

```
t tjjji ibbbbhhhhhp puuuu
```

If the two consecutive characters are same then need to print space between two consecutive characters....if the consecutive characters are greater than two no need to add space.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char s[100]="ttjjjiibbbbhhhhhppuuuu";
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(s);i++){
      if(s[i]!=s[i-1] && s[i]==s[i+1]){
        s[i+1]=' ';
    }
}
printf("%s",s);
}
```

my output:

```
t j ji b b h h hp u u
```

What mistake i made??

Comment: Why is not `t t jjji ibbbbhhhhhp puuuu`?
There are two consecutive `t`.

Comment: @ZongruZhan sorry sir i typed wrongly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution: Calculate the length of consective characters and handle the special case(Length == 2).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char s[100] = "ttjjjiibbbbhhhhhppuuuu";
  char tmp_ch = s[0];
  int cnt = 1;
  
  for (int i = 1; i < strlen(s); i++) {
    while (s[i] == tmp_ch) {
      cnt++;
      i++;
      if (i == strlen(s)) {
        break;
      }
    }
    if (cnt == 2) {
      putchar(tmp_ch);
      putchar(' ');
      putchar(tmp_ch);
    } else {
      for (int j = 0; j < cnt; j++) {
        putchar(tmp_ch);
      }
    }

    tmp_ch = s[i];
    cnt = 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your primary mistake is writing to your input when the string needs to grow. That's not going to work well and is hard to debug.

This is typical of C Code: measure once, process once. Same-ish code appears twice.

Variables:

```
int counter;
char *ptr1;
char *ptr2;
char *t;
```

Step 1: measure

```
for (ptr1 = s; *ptr1; ptr1++)
{
    ++counter;
    if (ptr1[0] == ptr1[1] && ptr1[0] != ptr1[2] && (ptr1 == s || ptr1[-1] != ptr1[0]))
        ++counter;
}
```

Step 2: copy and process

```
t = malloc(counter + 1);
for (ptr1 = s, ptr2 = t; *ptr1; ptr1++)
{
    *ptr2++ = *ptr1;
    if (ptr1[0] == ptr1[1] && ptr1[0] != ptr1[2] && (ptr1 == s || ptr1[-1] != ptr1[0]))
        *ptr2++ = ' ';
}
ptr2[0] = '\0';
```

Comment: Hello sir in first step why u used ptr ? because u doesn't declare it @Joshua

Comment: @Heisenberg: Poor editing. Fixed. Anyway, here's the thing of stackoverflow; you get to debug the answer.

Comment: Ok sir thank you understood now!!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use `strspn()` to get the number of consecutive characters as you work down the string. The prototype for `strspn()` is:

```c
    size_t strspn(const char *s, const char *accept);
```

Where `strspn()` returns the number of bytes in the initial segment of `s` which consist only of bytes from `accept`. (e.g. using the current character in a 2-character string as `accept`, it gives the number of times that character appears in sequence)

Tracking the number of charters returned and updating an offset from the beginning allows you to simply loop letting `strspn()` do the work as you work though your string. All you are concerned with is when `strspn()` returns `2` identifying where two, and only two, of the same character are adjacent to one another.

You can do:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
  
  char *input = "ttjjjiibbbbhhhhhppuuuu";
  char chstr[2] = {0};            /* 2 char string for accept parameter */
  size_t nchr = 0, offset = 0;    /* no. chars retured, current offset */
  
  *chstr = input[offset];         /* initialize with 1st char */
  /* while not at end, get number of consecutive character(s) */
  while (*chstr && (nchr = strspn (input + offset, chstr))) {
    if (nchr == 2) {              /* if 2 - add space */
      putchar (input[offset]);
      putchar (' ');
      putchar (input[offset]);
    }
    else {  /* otherwise, loop nchr times outputting char */
      size_t n = nchr;
      while (n--)
        putchar(input[offset]);
    }
    offset += nchr;               /* add nchr to offset */
    *chstr = input[offset];       /* store next char in string */
  }
  
  putchar ('\n');                 /* tidy up with newline */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ /bin/space_between_2
t tjjji ibbbbhhhhhp puuuu
```

Let me know if you have further questions concerning the use of `strspn()`.

Comment: Nice sir good approach